# cd ~/ returns "/home/[myuser]/: not found [No such file or directory]"

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Working on a new cloud instance of RedHat (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)).

I'm tring to access user folder and I'm getting not found. I also can't create such because I don't have sudo rights.

`cd ~/`

returns

```
/home/[myuser]/: not found [No such file or directory]
```

Should I contact the admin or there is another way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create user without (with impropoer) home dir.

however if you are to connect to the host, you must have a valid home dir.

What you show implies

- home dir field is not, or improperly set in /etc/passwd,
- you home dir is not created.

grep you id using

```
 id
```

this is a int like 1001 or 501, let's use `1001`.

now grep it in `/etc/passwd`

```
 grep :1001: /etc/passwd
```

look for a line where 1001 is third field (`:` is the separator), the sixth field is your home dir. If not set, got your system admin.